# Angular 2 : external js file variables are accessible from component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am trying to import an external js file to my component.

external.js

```
var x=9;
```

component.ts

```
import '../../assets/api/external.js';
declare let x: any;
....
console.log(x);
```

and I get :

```
ERROR ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

How can I access x from the component? It does not complain about not being able to find the js file.

Comment: in angular cli json are you adding the script to make it as public  "scripts": [
    "..your script"
], you have to add it to json.

Comment: try to `export let x = 9` in the .js file and then import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add your script in angular-cli.json as a global script.

```
 "scripts": [
"../external.js",
"../node_modules/.....min.js",
"../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/....js"
],
```

let know if it helps.
Here is the reference link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Answer (score 1):

your import `js` didn't export any function or class to your component.
The `MDN` interface for import subscribe the `import 'module_name'`:

> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values.

So change your and add the class or function then export.

Answer (score 1):

You can call varibale from anthoer script in Angular application.

Step 1. Create demo.js file in assests/javascript folder.

```
export function test1(){
    console.log('Calling test 1 function');
}
```

Step 2. Create demo.d.ts file in assests/javascript folder.

```
export declare function test1();
```

Step 3. Use it in your component

```
//User defined file path
import { test1 } from '../assets/javascript/demo'; 
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(test1());
  }
}
```

Note: js and .d.ts file name shoule be same